# Install global dependency manualy

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

I'm working on a project which is gonna be deployed on a VM(Windows OS) but I can't download dependencies because all npm ports are blocked and there is no way to open them.
So the only way to solve this is to zip all local dependencies and then copy them to the VM. This is pretty simple however I use two global dependencies: PM2 and pm2-windows-service.

My question is how to copy these two dependencies to the VM and then make them global ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install global dependencies locally and use them from the node_modules path for example:

```
node node_modules/.bin/pm2 start app.js
```

instead of

```
pm2 start app.js
```

Actually I tend to recommend using the minimal amount of global dependencies ie. only npm

Answer (score 1):

From [npm-install](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install):

```
npm install -g <tarball file>
```

And:

> A package is:
>
> ```
> a) a folder containing a program described by a package.json file
> b) a gzipped tarball containing (a)
> ...
> ```

And also:

> `npm install <tarball file>`:
>
> Install a package that is sitting on the filesystem. Note: if you just
>   want to link a dev directory into your npm root, you can do this more
>   easily by using npm link.
>
> **Tarball requirements:**
>
> - The filename must use .tar, .tar.gz, or .tgz as the extension.
> - The package contents should reside in a subfolder inside the tarball (usually it is called package/). npm strips one directory
>     layer when installing the package (an equivalent of tar x
>     --strip-components=1 is run).
> - The package must contain a package.json file with name and version properties.
>
> **Example:**
>
> ```
> npm install ./package.tgz
> ```

So just copy both (packed) packages and run the above command inside your VM, like `npm i -g /pm2.tar`.